# Issue in describing Opsworks stack using boto

Tags: python-2.7, boto3

Below is the simple code snippet, which I'm trying to run, it gives exception.
I've configured AWS on my local and I'm able to describe the same stack in the AWS Opsworks UI. Can someone help here, with what could be the reason:

```
import boto3
client=boto3.client('opsworks')
response=client.describe_stack_summary(
    StackId="6efce529-0b77-43dc-981b-ff20b906c4ae"
)
print(response)
```

Stacktrace for error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "botoTest.py", line 9, in <module>
StackId="6efce529-0b77-43dc-981b-ff20b906c4ae"
File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/botocore/client.py", line 320, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/botocore/client.py", line 623, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred 
(ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the DescribeStackSummary 
operation: Unable to find stack with ID 6efce529-0b77-43dc-981b- 
ff20b906c4ae
```

Comment: It is possible the credentials on your local and on OpsWork console are for two different users/accounts.

Comment: If I try to achieve the same result with AWS CLI , it is working for me.